# UserManager.FindAsync(username, password) not available in ASP.NET 5 / Identity 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to upgrade a project to ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6.

The UserManager that came with AspNet.Identity used to have a FindAsync method where I could pass in a username and password. It doesn't seem to be there anymore.

I don't think I need the SigninManager or Authentication as I'm using  JWT Bearer Authentication. I just need to check the username and password are valid before I grant an access token,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use `UserManager.FindByNameAsync()` to find the user object then check its password:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
if(user!=null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
{
    // user is valid do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It  looks like it has been renamed to:

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
```

you can view the [source code for UserManager here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs)